# How include Facelets page as javascript file into Facelets page

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, facelets

I create simple page with messages:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<f:view locale="#{languageController.locale}"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var message = '#{msg.validation_message}';
            var notValidMessage = '#{msg.not_submit_message}';
            var notValidCurrentFormMessage = '#{msg.partial_valid}';
            var hap = 'happiness';
        </script>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

And I have a JS file for validation form:

```
function validateForm(formId, elementIds, lang) {
    var valid = validateFields(formId, elementIds, lang);
    if (valid) {        
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

On Facelets page I include Facelets file as JS file:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="errorNames.xhtml"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="validation.js"/>
```

But it seems that page `errorNames.xhtml` is not included correctly.

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: what do you mean with "seems that page errorNames not included correctly". Do you get an error?

Comment: @roel When I try to open in source code genreted page `errorNames.xhtml` I get empty page

Comment: @Ray You cannot serve a X/HTML page as a script; the browser will not be able to interpret this in a meaningful way. Consider using Facelets templates to in-line this code - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct is absolutely not valid. The `<h:outputScript>` must point to a physically valid JS file.

Your best bet is using `<ui:include>` to include it inline.

So, a `/WEB-INF/includes/script.xhtml` (no, no XML prolog, no doctype, no html/head/body and the f:view must go in master template; below code is complete as-is):

```html
<ui:composition
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:outputScript>
        var message = '#{msg.validation_message}';
        var notValidMessage = '#{msg.not_submit_message}';
        var notValidCurrentFormMessage = '#{msg.partial_valid}';
        var hap = 'happiness';
    </h:outputScript>
</ui:composition>
```

*(be aware that this is prone to errors whenever one of those variables contain a special character in JS such as a singlequote, a newline, etc, use if necessary [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`#{of:escapeJS()}`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/current/of/escapeJS.fn.html) to escape JS)*

And in `/some.xhtml`:

```html
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/script.xhtml" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="validation.js" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the way how you're using resource `library` is not entirely right. Carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)